# How to integrate Groovy with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, groovy

I'm new to Groovy.. But I have knowledge in Mongodb as DBA. How to integrate Groovy with MongoDB? Please let me know the websites to refer. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

The "latest and greatest" in Groovy MongoDB libraries is [GORM 5](http://grails.io/post/133798408743/announcing-gorm-5-suite)

Comment: ..and that is red hot, just one week old!